# change statelistdrawable text color android button

Tags: android, button, android-button, android-selector

I'm developing android application

I have a different background drawable and text color for each status of the button (pressed , normal)

I have created statelistdrawable object to be able to add the background drawable , but my problem now is how to set the text color

can any one help please ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Button is a TextView and you can call [`button.setTextColor(someColorStateList)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29) on a TextView.

Here is how to do it programmatically:

```
   ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{R.attr.state_selected},
                    new int[]{-R.attr.state_selected},
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.GREEN,
                    Color.BLUE,
                    Color.RED});
    TextView textView = ... some textView or button
    textView.setTextColor(colorStateList);
```

You can of course do the same with xml configuration (define your [colorStateList in xml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) and associate it with the button text color property `android:textColor="@drawable/mycolorstatelist"`

Comment: Thanks ben75 for sharing I will give it a try and get back to you