# set specific color to ColorStateList programmatically

Tags: android, textview, textcolor, android-selector

I created StateListDrawable from my question [Add Color "#e3bb87" to StateListDrawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382854/add-color-e3bb87-to-statelistdrawable-programmatically) , but TextView.setTextColor does not take StateListDrawable  (strange it works in layout) but ColorStateList  . I read this [change statelistdrawable text color android button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604385/change-statelistdrawable-text-color-android-button)

In the constructor of ColorStateList, it only accepts arrays of int

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{R.attr.state_selected},
                    new int[]{-R.attr.state_selected},
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.GREEN,
                    Color.BLUE,
                    Color.RED});
```

The color is not defined in colors.xml because I download this color attribute. How can I define like this ?

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{R.attr.state_pressed}
            },
            **getThisColor**("#e3bb87"));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] { new int[] { R.dimen.padding_large } },
            new int[] {Color.parseColor("#e3bb87")});
```

Comment: Fortunately I was first. :D :)

Comment: What is the significance of dimen.padding_large here?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `valueOf()` method of `ColorStateList` that returns a `ColorStateList` containing a single color:

```
ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#e3bb87"))
```